# Can not choose number of periods for forecasting any other than variable length

Tags: r, time-series, prediction, forecasting, forecast

I want to predict a time series from a model I estimate with `tslm` from the `forecast` package. Here is some data:

```
x <- ts(rnorm(120,0,3) + 1:120 + 20*sin(2*pi*(1:120)/12), frequency=12, start= c(2000, 01, 01))
y <- ts(x + rnorm(length(x)), frequency=12, start= c(2000, 01, 01))
df <- data.frame(y, x)
```

So we have an (independent) variable `x` with some pattern and a (dependent) variable `y` which appears to be a noisy version of x. I fit the model like this:

```
fit <- tslm(y ~ trend + season + x, df)
```

`summary(fit)` looks okay, since `x` is highly significant and estimate is close to 1. But running `forecast(fit, h=20)` gives me an error:

> ... variable lengths differ (found for 'x') ...

`forecast(fit, h= length(x))` works (although `plot(forecast(fit, h= length(x)))` looks very strange, but this is an other question).

Comment: If you have predictors in your model (`x`, `trend`, `season`), you must also include future values for these predictors in the forecast using the argument `newdata`, e.g. `newdata = data.frame(x = ..., trend = ..., season = ...)` (I believe `tsml` handles trend ans seasonal automatically as stated in the documentation, but perhaps best to be explicit?). The behavior observed in the plot is interesting! It seems like it recycles `x` if no `newdata` for `x` is included? I'm sure it is intended, but I can't find anything about it in the documentation.

Comment: @henrik_ibsen Using `forecast(tslm(y ~ trend + season, df), h= 20)` works without providing future values. If I use `tslm(y ~ trend + season + x, df)` it doesn't work, but I do not know the future values (that is what I want to know). That confuses me.

Comment: I believe that is because `tslm` automatically generates newdata for those variables because they are deterministic, i.e. we know what they will be in the future. If we define the forecast as `f <- forecast(tslm(y ~ trend + season, df), h= 20)`, then we can find the automatically generated newdata here: `f$newdata`. Regarding your final point, and if I understand you correctly: not knowing the future value of a predictor is a normal problem in forecasting, i.e. to forecast `y` one must first forecast `x`.

Comment: @henrik_ibsen " i.e. to forecast y one must first forecast x": for sure. Anyway, that was really helpful: "we can find the automatically generated newdata here"! Thanks a lot. This solves my problem! If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To forecast `y` into the future using predictors like `x`, `trend` and `seasonal`,
new data for the predictors must be supplied for the number of periods ahead you want to forecast.
This can be done using the argument `newdata` in `forecast.lm` (see ?`forecast.lm`)

Under follows an example with only x as predictor where we want to forecast `y` for the next 12 months

```
library(forecast)
n <- 132 
set.seed(1337)
x <- ts(rnorm(n,0,3) + 1:n + 20*sin(2*pi*(1:n)/12), frequency=12, start= c(2000, 01, 01))
#Dividing x into a train and test set, where the test set will be the data we use to forecast ´y´
xtrain <- window(x, end=c(2009, 12))
xtest <- data.frame(x=window(x, start=c(2010, 1)))
y <- window(ts(x + rnorm(length(x)), frequency=12, start= c(2000, 01, 01)), end=c(2009,12))
dftrain <- data.frame(y, x=xtrain)

fit <- tslm(y ~ x, dftrain)
f <- forecast(fit, newdata=xtest)
plot(f)
```

What makes the `tslm` function a bit 'special' is that it generates data for trend and seasonality automatically if this is specified, e.g.

```
fit2 <- tslm(y~trend+season)
f2 <- forecast(fit2, h=12)
plot(f2)
```

Here it automatically generates data for the `newdata` argument, which can be found here:

```
f2$newdata #Beware, season is a factor: str(f2$newdata)
```

If we combine trend, season and `x`, we get

```
fit3 <- tslm(y~trend+season+x, data=dftrain)
f3 <- forecast(fit3, newdata=xtest)
f3$newdata
```

Strange! Even though we expect it to use all predictors for the forecast, trend and season is not included in `f$newdata`. We can try to include trend and seasonal manually and check if we get the same results:

```
#Using `seasonaldummy` from the `forecast` package to generate the seasonal dummy matrix. 
#Beware: `forecast::seasonaldummy` use December as reference period by default, while `tslm` use January.
#This should not affect our results, except for the interpretation of the seasonal coefficients.
dftrain2 <- data.frame(y, x=xtrain, customTrend=1:(n-12), forecast::seasonaldummy(xtrain))
dftest2 <- data.frame(x=xtest, customTrend = (n-12+1):n, forecast::seasonaldummy(xtrain, h=12))
fit4 <- tslm(y~customTrend+Jan+Feb+Mar+Apr+May+Jun+Jul+Aug+Sep+Oct+Nov+x, data=dftrain2)
f4 <- forecast(fit4, newdata = dftest2)

f4$newdata #now everything is included. 

#Compare the forecasts generated by fit3 and fit4:
f3$mean - f4$mean #Close enough
all.equal(f3$mean, f4$mean) #Point forecast
all.equal(f3$lower, f4$lower) #PIs
all.equal(f3$upper, f4$upper) #PIs
```

We can also include the seasonal variable as `factor`, which is a bit easier (but less intuitive in my opinion), and yields completely identical coefficient estimates as `fit3`.

```
dftrain3 <- data.frame(y, x=xtrain, customTrend=1:(n-12), customSeason = rep(factor(1:12, levels=1:12), 10))
dftest3 <- data.frame(x=xtest, customTrend = (n-12+1):n, customSeason = factor(1:12, levels=1:12))
fit5 <- tslm(y~customTrend+customSeason+x, data=dftrain3)
all(coefficients(fit3) == coefficients(fit5))
f5 <- forecast(fit5, newdata = dftest3)
f5$newdata
```

Comment: Thanks! So far I ended up using `forecast(tslm(y~ trend + season + x, data= dftrain), h=12, newdata= cbind.data.frame(forecast(tslm(y~trend+season), h=12)$newdata, x= xtest))` which seems a little easier to me. So basically I feed the `newdata` argument with the newdata generated by `forecast(tslm(y~trend+season), h=12)$newdata` and add a column with`xtest`.